# Custom Infopath control for browser-enabled forms - is it possible?

Tags: infopath, infopath-forms-services

So, is it possible? 
I need to choose domain users in web-enabled Infopath form and now I am using drop down list with custom web service, but may be possible write custom control for web-enabled Infopath form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Infopath contact selector control instead.  [Here's how to set it up .](http://blogs.msdn.com/infopath/archive/2007/02/28/using-the-contact-selector-control.aspx)